# Is it possible to install a Fedora package on RedHat Linux Server?

Tags: linux, redhat, fedora, kdevelop

I would like to install KDevelop on RedHat Linux Server v.7. Although there is no an appropriate RPM for RH Server, such an RPM does exist for Fedora.

Since both Fedora and RH Server have the same code base and are supported by the same company, is it possible to install a Fedora RPM on RH Server? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Add the EPEL repository from Fedora](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/install-epel-and-additional-repositories-on-centos-and-red-hat/) to the list of repositories.
Once the repository will be added, you will be able of installing kdevelop using `yum`.